# Access Google analytics Demo account

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google analytics is offering access [Demo account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?utm_source=GA%20Education&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_content=GA%20blog&utm_campaign=Demo%20Account). But is the data available from the API?

I tried testing it for simple pageviews, but I get an error
`insufficientPermissions: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.`,
even from the Query Explorer.
Can someone please confirm its availability and how to properly access it?

It becomes useful to understand all scenarios and build a test app with demo data before putting it public.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the Analytics Reporting API cannot access the demo account. From the [docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342#limitations):

> The demo account cannot be used with the Analytics Reporting API.
>   Attempting to access the demo account with the Analytics Reporting API
>   will result in a permissions error: `(403) insufficientPermissions`.

Comment: Is there any alternative you are aware of?

Comment: @arjun Follow this Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264088/create-a-demo-account-thats-usable-with-the-analytics-reporting-api-google-an