# Create a demo account that's usable with the Analytics Reporting API? [Google Analytics]

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I need to test some things with a Google Analytics View, but the default demo account that Google offers does not allow user to use the Analytics Reporting API :

> You cannot use the demo account with the Analytics Reporting API. Attempts to do so result in a permissions error: (403) insufficientPermissions.

[Source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en)

I just need to replicate a view with different data already.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot replicate views with data. A view will always start empty.

However you can simply register a Google Analytics account and send lots of bogus data (either by setting up a web page with tracking code and call it repeatedly, or set a cron job to fire call via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)) (this will happen in realtime, so you need to wait a few days before you have enough useable data. There is not way to bulk-create hits for a longer timeframe).

If you just want to test the API it probably matter that much what data you use, so a mock account should work just fine.